# PHP RSA Signature Variable Not Verifying

Tags: php, base64, rsa, signature, phpseclib

I have two functions.  One function generates the signature for some data.  The other function verify the signature for the data.  The problem I am facing is that the verification does not return true.  I am using phpseclib library http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/2.0/examples.html

```
    public function generate(){
    $rsa = new RSA();
    /*$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(RSA::PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS1);
    extract($rsa->createKey());
    return "$publickey\r\n\r\n$privatekey";*/

    $rsa->loadKey(base64_decode(env('RSA_PRIVATE_KEY')));

    $data = 'hello';

    $rsa->setSignatureMode(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
    $signature = $rsa->sign($data);

    return base64_encode($signature);

}

public function verify(Request $request){
    $rsa = new RSA();

    $data = 'hello';

    $signature = 'HTwI8TU9tIGBSUOWxCI95oILWxdnY9K9rizZbusQMM5+vlD4IiFuU5YghWnRTO+zB4GKUxhOcEaf127X5Hs7m4M76etol7dxxxkFw8097OWuU+bh2YskFB2GLWjzRdamg7RyWYznlePyBlPH8QeBHiRMvHHivabGOmNTkgsF09E=';

    $rsa->loadKey(base64_decode(env('RSA_PUBLIC_KEY'))); // public key
    return $rsa->verify($data, base64_decode($signature)) ? 'verified' : 'unverified';

}
```

If I combine the two functions into one function like this, it works fine.

```
    $rsa = new RSA();
    /*$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(RSA::PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS1);
    extract($rsa->createKey());
    return "$publickey\r\n\r\n$privatekey";*/

    $rsa->loadKey(base64_decode(env('RSA_PRIVATE_KEY')));

    $data = 'hello';

    $rsa->setSignatureMode(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
    $signature = $rsa->sign($data);

    $signature = base64_encode($signature);

    $rsa->loadKey(base64_decode(env('RSA_PUBLIC_KEY'))); // public key
        return $rsa->verify($data, base64_decode($signature)) ? 'verified' : 'unverified';
```

I do not understand. I have tested many ways and the signature is the same but does not verify.  I am trying to sign on one API end point and verify on another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `verify` function you're not doing this:

```
$rsa->setSignatureMode(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
```

You're doing it in your `generate` function but not your `verify` function.

In your combined function the same signature mode is being used because the same object is being used.